# PySpark data frame schema passing dynamically

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark data frame like below:

```
           >>> df2.show() 
           +--------------------+                                                          
           |               value|
           +--------------------+
           |[Name, Number, Sa...|
           |        [A, 1, 2000]|
           |        [B, 2, 3000]|
           |        [C, 3, 4000]|
            +--------------------+
```

Now i am trying to remove the column name as Value and get the schema as below

```
           +--------+--------+--------+                                                    
           |Name    |Number  |  Salary|
           +--------+--------+--------+
           |       A|       1|    2000|
           |       B|       2|    3000|
           |       C|       3|    4000|
           +--------+--------+--------+
```

The code i used as below:

```
  length = len(df2.select('value').take(1)[0][0])
  df2.select([df2.value[i] for i in range(length)]).show()
```

and the output i am getting as below which is not correct

```
          +--------+--------+--------+                                                    
          |value[0]|value[1]|value[2]|
          +--------+--------+--------+
          |    Name|  Number|  Salary|
          |       A|       1|    2000|
          |       B|       2|    3000|
          |       C|       3|    4000|
          +--------+--------+--------+
```

Have used spark version - 2.4.0 , Python Version - 3.6.12

Appreciate your support

Comment: Be careful because row ordering is not deterministic. You could be taking the wrong row

Comment: Bad records can be handled as explained in this blogpost : https://anish749.github.io/spark/exception-handling-spark-data-frames/